# Multiple data conversion with groovy

Tags: java, groovy, data-conversion

I have a problem doing several conversions on some data.
I get a response from a request that contains base64 encoded bytes and I'd like to get them in hexa.

This is a String type:

```
log.info "type data base 64 : " + dataBase64.getClass().getName()
INFO:type data base 64 : java.lang.String
```

Then I decode it:

```
data = dataBase64.decodeBase64() 
log.info "type data : " + data.getClass().getName()

INFO:type data : [B  => ?? there is something strange here

log.info "data = " + data
INFO:data = [0, 33, 0, 0, -74, 0, 16, 0, 0, 1, 0, 10, 3, 0, 0, 0, 28, 120, -45, 28, 90, 95, 25, -14, -119, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want this data in bytes in order to recover an address in bytes 22 to 24
If I do

```
log.info "dataHex = "  + data.encodeHex()
INFO:dataHex = 00210000b60010000001000a030000001c78d31c5a5f19f289ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want to recover the `19f289` part. The problem is that I cannot convert data[22] to data[24]
`data[22].encodeHex` fails (the data[22] type is Byte, not Byte[])

If I try to use toHexString on each byte required, I encounter a problem when handling negative values

```
for (i=22;i<25;i++)
{
    myInt = data[i]
    log.info Integer.toHexString(myInt) 
}
```

gives

```
INFO:19
INFO:fffffff2
INFO:ffffff89
```

Is there any clean way to do this ? 
I could try to extract the substring from dataHex after conversion to String (I haven't tried it yet) but I don't understand why I can convert simply a byte to hexadecimal

if anyone knows ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

After improving my knowledge of Groovy thanks to a collegue, here is a cleaner way to recover the data I want :

```
dataHex = data.encodeHex().toString()
log.info "data hex in bytes = ${dataHex}"

// group data by bytes
def dataHexBy2 = dataHex.toList().collate(2)*.join()
log.info " group by 2 " + dataHexBy2

def address = ""

for (i=22;i<25;i++)
{
    address = address + dataHexBy2[i]
} 
log.info "address = ${address}"
```

and I finally get address = 19f289